# How to consume a custom generated d.ts file in typescript angular2 cli webapplication

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am building an angular2 application in typescript. I have a file named myinterfaces.d.ts which is a definitions file generated from java using an open source java=>typescript generator. Now I would like to use myinterfaces.d.ts in my components, services etc. Now tab completion in IntelliJ finds these definitions and this is what it sticks inside my component.ts when I use ALT+Enter on the usage of ObjectDto to let the IDE find the reference

```
import {ObjectDto} from "../../../../../generated/target/myinterfaces";
```

but what ends up happening during "ng serve" followed by reloading the browser is that it is looking for myinterfaces.js which of course does not exist since this is not a source ts file and there is no corresponding .js file; instead it is a definitions file.

On the web and in stack overflow I find people talking about using node_modules/typings etc but not a custom standalone foo.d.ts file in angular2 sitting in a random directory not under node_modules.

I am looking for the right syntax in my usage in components.ts files to consume my myinterfaces.d.ts to get code assistance but exclude them from compilation in typescript and errors looking for myinterfaces.js at the time of execution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show what the file contains, especially the definition of ObjectDto?

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, This file is a whole bunch of exported typescript interfaces that look like java pojo objects. The generator does parse base classes in java and hence you can imagine the generated typescript interfaces extending other interfaces in typescript. I cannot add the contents of the interfaces because it is proprietary but you can imagine a "Person" class or any general data transfer object with a class hierarchy. Thank you.

Comment: Post something that closely looks like what the file contains. In particular, is it interfaces, or classes.